# heteroscedasticity and sample size

Tags: heteroscedasticity

How to explain the situation that heteroskedasticity disappear as the sample size grows larger? is there any evidence shows that the existence of heteroskedasticity has something to do with the sample size?

Comment: Please can you show us an example of this phenomenon

Comment: What does "a large difference between the size of the observations" mean? 

You can certainly have heteroskedasticity with a large sample size. In fact, if your small sample and your large sample are both random from the same population, heteroskedasticity ought to stay the same.

Comment: This remains a duplicate, even after the edit. If you can provide an example of this, as @RobertLong requests, there may be something we can say beyond what is already contained in the linked thread. Until then, there is nothing more to say.